# Bind details form to listbox in WPF/MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am getting on with WPF/MVVM, and am a little stuck on what I think might be a basic question.

I have a View Model - viewmodelTitles.  This exposes an ObservableCollection of viewmodelTitle objects.  (Titles, in this example, is Mr., Mrs., Dr., etc etc).

I have succesfully bound this a ListView.

What I want to do now is have it so that when the user clicks on an item in the ListView a second part of the form - the 'details' part - shows the details of the selected viewmodelTitle object.  The Description property of the viewmodelTitle object will be shown in a textbox ... thus allowing a user to edit it.

(In this example there is only one property of the viewmodelTitle object - Description - but imagine this were a 'person' object ... the 'details' form would be where we edit firstname, lastname, address, age, date of birth, etc.)

I know I can do something in the event that fires when a selection changes ... but it seems that there might be a more 'data-bindy' way of doing this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `SelectedItem` of the `ListView` a property on your view-model. You can then bind that property to the `DataContext` of the detail view.

Here is a small diagram that attempts to visualize how to implement master-detail in MVVM:

[image: Master-detail in MVVM]

Comment: This is the way that I almost always go.  In addition, I typically house a collection of ViewModels on my ViewModel instead of the items directly.  So in your viewModelTitles, an ObservableCollection of viewModelTitle.  This way, when you select an item in the list box, a Title ViewModel is bound as the context of your detail pane, along with the commands, properties and methods that make it up.

Comment: I added a property on the viewmodelTitles ('SelectedTitle') with a get-ter that returned a private member _selectedTitle of type viewmodelTitle.  It's set-ter simply stored the 'value' into this private member, and called the RaisePropertyChanged event.

I then added:

SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTitle, Mode=TwoWay}"

to the XAML of the ListView.

Finally, I specified 

DataContext="{Binding SelectedTitle}" 

in the grid that wrapped all the text boxes I needed (ok ... just the one in this case!)

So, thanks very much for the help.  I see and understand how this works.  Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView x:Name="listTitles" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=viewmodelTitles}">...
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=listTitles, Path=SelectedItem.Description}" />
```